# pg_basebackup not running even after trying all the methods

Tags: postgresql, backup, configuration

I configured `pg_basebackup` on another server, where it is running perfectly, but in one of the servers `pg_basebackup` is not running at all. Below are the error details. I tried multiple ways to troubleshoot, but didn't solve the issue; please help. The PostgreSQL version is 11.7.

```
-bash-4.2$ pg_basebackup -p 5432 -U postgres -Ft -D /var/lib/pgsql/backup/cluster1day1
pg_basebackup: could not get write-ahead log end position from server: ERROR:  could not open file "./.pg_ident.conf.swp": Permission denied
pg_basebackup: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/pgsql/backup/cluster1day1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You did something that you shouldn't do: you used the `root` user to edit a file in the PostgreSQL data directory using `vi`.

Then the session got interrupted, and now you are stuck with a `swp` file in the data directory that is owned by root. The operating system user `postgres`, who reads the files in the data directory to send them to `pg_basebackup`, cannot read that file and throws the appropriate error message.

Solution: remove the offending file from the data directory, and everything will work again.

Comment: your solution worked, thanks a lot. I have one more question, I am new to postgresqlDB. But I need to configure High Availability, I read some postgres replication stuff. But colud you please suggest , the solution. I am planning to configure Stream Replication, but is this works in real time properly, thanks in advance, Sasidhar

Comment: This has nothing to do with this question, so you would have to ask a new question. But that question will be closed, because it is too broad and asks for software recommendation. No relational database system can provide hard real-time guarantees.